# Working with anonymous modules in Ruby

Tags: ruby, module, anonymous

Suppose I make a module as follows:

```
m = Module.new do
  class C
  end
end
```

Three questions:

- Other than a reference to `m`, is there a way I can access `C` and other things inside `m`?
- Can I give a name to the anonymous module after I've created it (just as if I'd typed "module ...")?
- How do I delete the anonymous module when I'm done with it, such that the constants it defines are no longer present?

Answer (score 7):

Three answers:

- Yes, using `ObjectSpace`. This code makes `c` refer to your class `C` without referencing `m`:

  ```
  c = nil  
  ObjectSpace.each_object { |obj|  
    c = obj if (Class === obj and obj.name =~ /::C$/)  
  }
  ```

  Of course this depends on there being no other classes named `C` anywhere in the program, but you get the idea.
- Yes, sort of. If you just assign it to a constant, like `M = m`, then `m.name` will return `"M"` instead of `nil`, and references like `M::C` will work. Actually, when I do this and type `M::C` in irb, I get `#<Module:0x9ed509c>::C`, but maybe that's a bug.
- I think it should be garbage collected once there are no references to it, i.e. when there are no instances or subtypes of `m` or `C`, and `m` is set to a different value or goes out of scope. If you assigned it to a constant as in the above point, you would need to change it to a different value too (though changing constants is generally ill-advised).

Answer (score 1):

I tried wdebeaum's second answert in Ruby 1.9.3-p0 and it didn't work.
`M::C` returned `NameError: uninitialized constant M::C` and `M.constants` returns `[]`

So you should try the approach suggested [here](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/167829)

```
m = Module.new do
  class self::C
  end
end
```

And you can use `m::C` as usual.

Answer (score 1):

## Define a NamedModule

Once way to handle this is to define your own kind of module that can be initialized with a name.

```
class NamedModule < Module
  attr_accessor :name

  def initialize(name, &block)
    super(&block)
    self.name = name
  end

  def to_s
    [self.class.name, name, object_id].join(':')
  end
end
```

Then you can do this:

```
piracy = NamedModule.new("Piracy") do
  def berate
    puts "Yer a #{adjectives.sample} #{nouns.sample}!"
  end

  private

  def adjectives
    %w[yella-bellied landlubbing]
  end

  def nouns
    %w[scallywag bilge-drinker]
  end
end

Sailor = Class.new
Sailor.send(:include, piracy)
Sailor.new.berate #=> "Yer a yella-bellied scallywag!"
```

Defining `to_s` gives you nice output in `ancestors`:

```
Sailor.ancestors 
#=> [Sailor, NamedModule:Piracy:70169997844420, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

### Update - use the Named gem

After my colleague and I had experimented with this, he wrote a small gem implementation. Check out the Named gem - [Rubygems](http://rubygems.org/gems/named) and [Github](https://github.com/adamhunter/named).